# MS Access VBA: Getting Error '13': Type Mismatch when calling a function from a different form

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013, type-mismatch

Edit: problem has been solved. See my answer in a separate post below!

I have two forms: Calendar and frmMagnet. When a text box in Calendar is clicked, it opens frmMagnet and is supposed to call a function declared in frmMagnet. But when I click on the text box, I get Error 13.

**Global Vars**

```
Private CalendarArray(42, 2) As Variant
```

**CalenderArray initialization**

```
Private Sub InitVariables()
  intMonthSelect = Month(CDate(CStr(Me.MonthComboBox) & " 1"))
  intYearSelect = Me.YearComboBox
  lngDate = CLng(DateSerial(intYearSelect, intMonthSelect, 1))
  strUnscheduledJobs = ""
  'Initialize CalendarArray
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To UBound(CalendarArray) - 1
      CalendarArray(i, 0) = lngDate - Weekday(lngDate) + 1 + i
      CalendarArray(i, 1) = CStr(Day(CalendarArray(i, 0)))
  Next i
End Sub
```

**Calendar method opening the magnet form**

```
Private Sub text1_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
  If Len(Me.ActiveControl.Text) > 2 Then
    Call OpenTextBox(Me.ActiveControl.Name)
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub OpenTextBox(ctlName As String)
  Dim ctlValue As Integer
  Dim DayOfMonth As Long

  ctlValue = Me.Controls(ctlName).Tag
  DayOfMonth = CalendarArray(ctlValue - 1, 0)
  DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMagnet"

  Call Forms("frmMagnet").PopulateHeaderText(DayOfMonth) 'THE ERROR IS ON THIS LINE!!!!!
End Sub
```

**frmMagnet method**

```
Public Sub PopulateHeaderText(theDate As Long)
  Me.Controls(HeaderText) = CStr(theDate)
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please include `CalenderArray` method implementation.

Comment: Just added that to the post. Thanks.

Comment: None of your VBA seems to be built events from the forms. I see no `textbox_click` or `Form_Open` subroutines and I see no functions in above code. Consider calling `PopulateHeaderText` subroutine in the OnOpen event of frmMagnet.

Comment: I updated the code with one of my double click functions (they all follow the same format). I didn't call PopulateHeaderText based on an OnOpen event because I needed to pass in the date. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to debug vba? If so which line causes the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my problem was

```
Me.Controls(HeaderText) = CStr(theDate)
```

needed quotations around HeaderText. The correct syntax is

```
Me.Controls("HeaderText") = CStr(theDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

On your method opening the magnet form you have this line of code;

```
 ctlValue = Me.Controls(ctlName).Tag
```

ctlValue is Long, are all of your fields tagged properly without any string characters (and no nulls)?

My advice here, is set a breakpoint (go into VBA and click in the bar on the left to get a red dot) at the start of the procedure. Then press your button to run the procedure, and step by step through until you find the offending line (use F8 to go step by step).

Lastly, it's worth turning on option explicit and declaring all your variables properly, it helps massively in this situation too.

Comment: This line is the offender: Call Forms("frmMagnet").PopulateHeaderText(DayOfMonth). I do have Option Explicit at the top of my module or whatever it's called. I only included the parts of my code I thought were relevant cause I didn't want to be the guy that just dumps the whole thing at you and say figure it out. But if you or someone think it would be helpful to have it all, I can post it.

Comment: Hehe I see, dumping the select parts at the top and the rest below for reference may be a good idea going forward - would help me look over it and figure it out much faster, imo! Glad you have it sorted though!!